# is there a way to switch between std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, refactoring

I have some legacy code written in C language and I'd like to refactor in C++14. I have to encounter a problem which I can't solve.

In plain old C, there was a way how to switch between arrays.

```
#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

const int sz = (machine == 1) ? NELEMS (errors1) : NELEMS (errors2);
const struct Error *error = (machine == 1) ? &errors1[0] : &errors2[0];
```

The code above works, but is somehow not readable. I'd like to use `std::array` because it can be easily manipulated with less and more readable code. `std::vector` uses heap memory and I'd like the result to be ROMable.

C++ code ternary operator **`const Error &error = (machine == 1) ? errors1 : errors2;`** it can't be used in such way, because `std::array<Error, 3> errors1` and `std::array<Error, 5> errors2` are different types! so how can be achieved the same functionality with `std::array` ?

Legacy C code

```
enum ErrorCode {

  ERR_NOT_FOUND,
  ERR_FORBIDDEN,
  ERR_INTERNAL,
  ERR_UNAVAILABLE,
  ERR_NO_RESPONSE,
  ERR_UNSUPPORTED,
  ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY,
  ERR_TIMEOUT
};

struct Error {
  int id;
  int code;
  const char *str;
};



static const struct Error errors1[] = {
    {1001, ERR_NOT_FOUND, "Not Found"},
    {1002, ERR_FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden"},
    {1003, ERR_INTERNAL, "Internal Error"}
};



static const struct Error errors2[] = {
  {1004, ERR_UNAVAILABLE, "Temporarly Unavailable"},
  {1005, ERR_NO_RESPONSE, "No Response"},
  {1006, ERR_UNSUPPORTED, "Unsupported"},
  {1007, ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY, "Insufficient Memory"},
  {1008, ERR_TIMEOUT, "Timeout"}
};

#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

char *error_to_string (char machine, int id) {
    const int sz = (machine == 1) ? NELEMS (errors1) : NELEMS (errors2);
    const struct Error *error = (machine == 1) ? &errors1[0] : &errors2[0];
    const char *str = "Unknown";

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (error[i].id == id) {
           str = error[i].str;
           break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

attempt to to achive moderen c++ code with same functionality as it is in C code

```
std::array<Error, 3> errors1= {{
    {1001, ERR_NOT_FOUND, "Not Found"},
    {1002, ERR_FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden"},
    {1003, ERR_INTERNAL, "Internal Error"}
}};

std::array<Error, 5> errors2= {{
    {1004, ERR_UNAVAILABLE, "Temporarly Unavailable"},
    {1005, ERR_NO_RESPONSE, "No Response"},
    {1006, ERR_UNSUPPORTED, "Unsupported"},
    {1007, ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY, "Insufficient Memory"},
    {1008, ERR_TIMEOUT, "Timeout"}
}};

const char *error_to_string (char machine, int id) {
    const char *str = (char*) "Unknown";
    const auto errors = (machine == 1) ? &errors1[0] : &errors2[0];

     for (auto error : errors) {
        if (error.id == id) {
            str = error.str;
            break;
        }
     }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda that searches for the error in a given array.

```
const char *error_to_string(const char machine, const int id) {
    const auto find_error = [id](const auto &errors) {
        for (const Error &error : errors) {
            if (error.id == id) return error.str;
        }
        return "Unknown";
    };
    return machine == 1 ? find_error(errors1) : find_error(errors2);
}
```

To extend this to many arrays, just use a `switch`.

```
const char *error_to_string(const char machine, const int id) {
    const auto find_error = [id](const auto &errors) {
        for (const Error &error : errors) {
            if (error.id == id) return error.str;
        }
        return "Unknown";
    };
    switch (machine) {
        case 1: return find_error(errors1);
        case 2: return find_error(errors2);
        case 3: return find_error(errors3);
        // ...
    }
    // probably want to handle this properly
    assert(false);
    return "Invalid machine";
 }
```

Comment: Tnx, Both solutions are nice but this is cleaner and can be used with multiple arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `N` arrays, not just two, simple metaprogramming can be of help:

```
template<char machine_id>
auto& get_errors() {
    if constexpr (machine_id == 0) 
        return errors1;
    else if constexpr (machine_id == 1) 
        return errors2;
    ...
    else
        return errorsN;
}

template<char machine_id>
const char* error_to_string_impl(char machine, int id) {
    if (machine == machine_id) {
        const auto& errors = get_errors<machine_id>();
        const auto fn = [id](Error e) { return e.id == id; };

        const auto it = std::find_if(errors.begin(), errors.end(), fn);
        if (it != errors.end())
            return it->str;
        return "Unknown";
    }

    if constexpr (machine_id + 1 < N)
        return error_to_string_impl<machine_id + 1>(machine, id);

    assert(false); // unreachable
    // return "Unknown machine";
}

const char* error_to_string(char machine, int id) {
    return error_to_string_impl<0>(machine, id);
}
```

`get_error` can also be implemented with overloading:

```
auto& get_errors(std::integral_constant<char, 0>) {
    return errors1;
}

auto& get_errors(std::integral_constant<char, 1>) {
    return errors2;
}

auto& get_errors(...) {
    return errorsN;
}
```

and

```
const auto& errors = get_errors(std::integral_constant<char, machine_id>{});
```

Comment: @MFnx, two errors fixed, thanks. After that it compiles.

Comment: upvoted, in my opinion, the templated get_errors function is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: The else in get_errors won't work. It compiles if machine_id == 0, but it doesn't if machine_id == 1. My guess is because the else statement is not checked at compile time. Workaround: if ((machine_id != 0) && (machine_id != 1)) return errorsN; Maybe there is a better workaround?

Comment: @MFnx, all `if`s should be `constexpr`, and second `if` should be `else if constexpr`. Otherwise the return types do not match and `auto` can't deduce it. I fixed the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, 2 independent ifs could cause a conflict of types. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, there is [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span):

```
const char* error_to_string (char machine, int id) {
    const auto errors = (machine == 1) ?
                            std::span<Error>{errors1} :
                            std::span<Error>{errors2};

     for (const auto& error : errors) {
        if (error.id == id) {
            return error.str;
        }
     }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Previously, you might use template:

```
template <typename Container>
const char* error_to_string(const Container& errors) {
     for (const auto& error : errors) {
        if (error.id == id) {
            return error.str;
        }
     }
    return "Unknown";
}

const char* error_to_string (char machine, int id) {
    return (machine == 1) ? error_to_string(errors1) : error_to_string(errors2);
}
```

Comment: Won't `std::span{errors1}` and `std::span{errors2};` have different types? The deduction guide is `template<class T, std::size_t N> span(std::array<T, N>&) -> span<T, **N**>;`.

Comment: Don't have `span` to test it :/ if common type doesn't work directly, we might explicitly use `std::dynamic_extent` for at least one `span`.